# Identifying jquery dom element without looping

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to identify the element directly in variable d instead of looping using each function. Please find the below DOM

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script src="../jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function() {

         var d = $("img", "#totaldiv");       
             d.each(function() {
                 if ($(this).attr("id") == "imgfour")
                     $(this).hide();
             });            

         });

     </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="totaldiv">
<img alt="hi image one" id="imgone" src="someimage" />
<img alt="hi image two" id="imgtwo" src="someimage" />
<img alt="hi image three" id="imgthree" src="someimage" />
<img alt="hi image four" id="imgfour" src="someimage" />
<img alt="hi image five" id="imgfive" src="someimage" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Actually my html is dynamic, just for illustration purpose i have provided this. I donot want to use $("#totaldiv #imgfour").hide(); (or) $("#totaldiv>#imgfour").hide();

Comment: what criteria is used for deciding if to show or hide?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have ids on the images, this is a one liner:

```
$("#imgfour").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
$('img#imgfour').hide();
```

Also why are you selecting by id in `#totaldiv` then looking for a different id?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loop and don't want to access the id directly, you could still use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
var d = $("img", "#totaldiv").filter("#imgfour");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add each img element a class

```
 <img alt="hi image one" class='myimage' id="imgone" src="someimage" />
 <img alt="hi image two"  class='myimage' id="imgtwo" src="someimage" />
 <img alt="hi image three" class='myimage'  id="imgthree" src="someimage" />
 <img alt="hi image four" class='myimage'  id="imgfour" src="someimage" />
 <img alt="hi image five"  class='myimage'  id="imgfive" src="someimage" />
```

2)  Hide/display all the elements which have 'myimage' class ,and then display/hide a specific element using id selector;

```
  $('.myimage').hide();
  $('.myimage#id4').show();
```

I hope this can help you .